# Disable Properties of model elements in GMF diagram editor

Tags: diagram, emf

I am really new in GMF/EMF and I have the following problem:
I am designing an Model editor and want to limit some user actions.
In the Properties view an diagram element has certain properties.
Now I want that the user is not able to change certain properties in this view, but the property has to stay and should not be deleted.
Is there a possibility to hide or disable the combobox/text input or to make a field readonly?

I would be really happy if you could help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can control the generated code for the model through the *generator model* file (*.genmodel*).

One of the properties of any model element attribute is just what you're looking for, the *Property Type*:

> Whether this feature should be included in the property sheet and
>   whether it should be editable.

The possible values are quite self-explanatory: None, Readonly and Editable.